# Making my copy version of Control_SearchBox.html

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, display-template

Within SharePoint 2013, I am in the Display Template -> Search Folder.   I see the Control_SearchBox.html page.  I downloaded a copy of this file.  I made tweaks to it based on some custom branding that I want.

What things do I need to do to this file to save it as a new name, and have it found as an additional search box when I want to add a custom search box to a publishing page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is:

- Give your html file a different name such as Control_CustomSearchBox.html.
- Inside this file change it's title to something different like: Custom Search Box.
- Add a Search Box webpart to your page and edit it's properties.
- In the Settings section change the Search box control Display Template to your new Custom Search Box.
- Save.

You can then export this search box webpart which now has it's display template set to your custom template and then add it to your webpart gallery. That should allow you to pick it from your webpart list when you need to add another one to a page.